# Angular Universal + CkEditor5: window is not defined

Tags: angular, ckeditor, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ckeditor5

I'm running an `` application that uses `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "1.2.3"` and a customised [build of CKeditor5](https://github.com/vhbazan/ckeditor5-build-classic/blob/develop/src/ckeditor.js).  I added SSR (Server Side Rendering - Angular Universal) support:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

And when I run `npm run dev:ssr` I got the following error:

```
  ReferenceError: window is not defined
        at Object../node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:117340:3242)
        at __webpack_require__ (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:20:30)
        at Object../src/app/post/new-edit-tutorial/new-edit-tutorial.component.ts (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:228444:23)
        at __webpack_require__ (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:20:30)
        at Object../src/app/post/post.module.ts (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:229101:39)
        at __webpack_require__ (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:20:30)
        at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:227134:23)
        at __webpack_require__ (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:20:30)
        at Object../src/app/app.server.module.ts (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:227205:22)
        at __webpack_require__ (/Users/user1/angular-ssr/dist/angular-ssr/server/main.js:20:30)

    A server error has occurred.
```

Is there any way to integrate CkEditor5 with Angular Universal? Or does anybody know any workaround?

Many thanks

Comment: Try using domino

Comment: @David thanks! I'll look into it and give it a go. I guess is this one, right?: 
https://github.com/fgnass/domino

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of examples out there. Also, depending on where your arror is, you can try not to instantiate the editor if the code is rendered server side, using `isPlatformbrowser` checks

Answer (score 0):

The `window` object is not available during server side rendering because your server (i.e. Node.JS) does not have a `window` object - it is a browser construct.

During SSR you cannot use code that references browser-specific constructs or objects like window or the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my point was to find a way to get the CkEditor working when using SSR, so I will go for the domino option as @David mentioned.

Comment: any solution to handle this issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem. There should be a solution for this. especially people migrating code